# HDInsight cluster creation cmdlet error

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-rm-template

I'm getting an error while trying to run the `cmdlet` in `powershell` to create a cluster using `ARM` template. The template runs fine if I run it from `Azure` portal.

> **Error :**
>
> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Cannot retrieve the
>   dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Could not load type 
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.FileUtilities' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common, Version=4.0.0.0
>
> **Command :**
>
> ```
> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName dev -TemplateFile C:\Users\vv\ARMTemplates\Clustercopy.json -TemplateParameterFile C:\Users\vv\ARMTemplates\paramFile.params.json
> ```

Comment: If possible, could you share your template and parameter json file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you re-check the parameters which you are passed in params.json file.

I'm able to create HDInsight cluster with same cmdlet:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName v-chepra -TemplateFile "H:\Azure Training\template (1)\template.json" -TemplateParameterFile "H:\Azure Training\template (1)\parameters.json"
```

[image]

Comment: I had problem with my parameter file. It worked after giving all the required parameters. Thanks!